# How to get indexes of all maximum values in python multidimensional np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to get all indexes of maximum values for each row from ndarray.
For example, i have

```
arr = np.array([[1, 3, 3], [1, 5, 4]])
```

And i would like to get indexes of all 3's from first row, and all 5's from second row.

```
np.where(((arr == arr[0].max()) | (arr == arr[1].max())))
```

And it returns

```
(array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 1], dtype=int64))
```

I want something like that but more universal for any amount of rows.
Because `np.where(arr == arr.argmax())` doesn't work like i want it to work. It only returns indexes of first maxium that it met in each row.

Comment: `(arr==arr.max(axis=1,keepdims=True)).nonzero()`?

Answer (score 1):

@Paul's answer in comments might be the best you can find. Writing it for readers. `arr.max(1)` find max in each row and `arr==arr.max(1,keepdims=True)` finds all elements in each row that are equal to corresponding max in that row. Finally `nonzero` returns indices of those elements:

```
(arr==arr.max(axis=1,keepdims=True)).nonzero()
```

output for OP's example:

```
(array([0, 0, 1]), array([1, 2, 1]))
```